# Domain Still Points to Old Server After Deleting Account

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, web-hosting, domain-name

Yesterday, I set up an account with 000webhost.com along side with a free domain name from dot.tk. I found out that my WordPress site's Admin is only compatible with >= PHP 5.3 and the server doesn't allow you to change the default PHP version (5.2.14) to 5.3. So I switched to 1freehosting.com because they allow you to use up to PHP 5.4. Now the domain still points to a 404 page on the 000webhost server. I changed the DNS servers on my dot.tk domain to point to my 1freehosting account. How long will it take for the changes to happen?

Answer (score 5):

It will take however long it takes for your cached record to expire on any resolver that has it cached. The TTL is a good estimate, but some DNS servers don't respect TTL.